# Sort a list of objects by the value of one of their properties, where only one value is of interest

Tags: c#, list, linq, sorting

I have a list of largeish objects, which I'd like to sort according to the values of one of the properties of the object.

However, all I care about is that those with a single given value of that property are at the top - all the other values, I don't care about their order. For example if I had:

```
 public class MyBigObject{
 
      public string Colour; 
      public string ImportantProperty;

 }
```

Now, imagine I had these:

```
 var a = new MyBigObject("red", "P2")
 var b = new MyBigObject("red", "P1")
 var c = new MyBigObject("red", "P3")
 var d = new MyBigObject("yellow", "P99")
 var e = new MyBigObject("yellow", "P3")
```

I want them sorted by colour, then by the ImportantProperty, where "P3" is the only value I'm interested in, and I want that first in the sorted list:

```
ListOfThoseObjects.OrderBy(c => c.Colour).ThenBy(x => x.???? where "P3" is the most important)
```

needs to yield:

```
 c (red / P3)
 a (red / P2)
 b (red / P1)
 e (yellow / P3)
 d (yellow / P99)
```

I want to be able to do this without having to list every possible value that ImportantProperty can be, as there are many and they may change out of my control. All I know is that P3 is the most important in terms of sorting.

Any help gratefully received!

Comment: `.OrderBy(c => c.Colour).ThenBy(x => x.ImportantProperty != "P3");`

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a ternary evaluating to 0 or 1:

```
ListOfThoseObjects
    .OrderBy(c => c.Colour)
    .ThenBy(x => x.ImportantProperty is "P3" ? 0 : 1);
```

Comment: So simple, that's awesome - thanks very much!

Comment: Doesn't work: "all I care about is that those with a single given value of that property are at the top". With ordering by color first the important property has lower priority and might come at the end

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yeah, I inferred that the order by colour was also needed considering it was in the example.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: OP specifically wants the **subordering**, not the main ordering, to favor P3. From the question: _"I want them sorted by colour, **then** by the ImportantProperty, where "P3" is the only value I'm interested in"_

Comment: @Flater: no, thats a common misunderstanding i often observed with conditional orderings. He mentioned it also explicitely if you look at my first comment. Actually he wants two groups and each group ordered by color, but the first group contains only items with ImportantProperty == "P3".

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Look at the example data. The P3's are not at the top of the list, they are at the top of **each color group** in the list. `yellow / P3` comes after `red / [any]` and before `yellow / [any]`. At several points (explanation, demo data _and_ code sample), it is made clear that ordering by color comes first. You're getting caught up on one ambiguous phrase in the beginning, and have skipped over the actual meat of the question.

Comment: yep - sorry, my fault. I misnamed the ImportantProperty - should have called it PropertyWithSpecialSortOrder. It's not the most important one to sort on, but it's the one that needs the ternary treatment you guys suggested. I've just tested it, working perfectly-  thanks all!

Comment: @chrisSpaceman: you're right. Now i'm confused what OP really wants and if the desrired result is really what he wants. Seems Johnathan understood it correctly then

Answer (score 1):

> However, all I care about is that those with a single given value of
> that property are at the top - all the other values, I don't care
> about their order

Thats not true. You are ordering by color too, so it seems you want to order first by that important property and then by the color:

```
var conditionalOrder = ListOfThoseObjects
    .OrderBy(x => x.ImportantProperty == "P3" ? 0 : 1)
    .ThenBy(x => x.Colour);
```

Comment: Yes, that's true - there are more things I'm sorting by in real life - however the ? 0 : 1 is exactly what I needed. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's important to note that `OrderBy` (and, by extension, `ThenBy`) performs the ordering based on the value it receives. That value doesn't necessarily have to come from your object. For example:

```
var rand = new Random();

myItems = myItems.OrderBy(item => rand.Next());
```

This effectively shuffles the items. Notice how the value (`rand.Next()`) is completely unrelated to the `item`.

In your case, you want to have a custom method with returns a specific value based on whether something is `P3` or not.

So, to do this very simply:

```
public int MyCustomOrdering(MyBigObject obj)
{
    if(obj.ImportantProperty == "P3")
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}
```

And then you can do:

```
myList = myList.OrderBy(item => MyCustomOrdering(item));
```

Or, if you prefer, in this specific simple example, you can condense this all into:

```
myList = myList.OrderBy(item => obj.ImportantProperty == "P3" ? 0 : 1);
```

But for more complex evaluations, it's suggested to abstract this into a method to keep things readable.

Comment: Great answer - much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can order by `bool` itself. Note, however, that `false < true`. So if you want items with `ImportantProperty == "P3"` be on the *top*, put it as

```
var result = ListOfThoseObjects
  .OrderBy(x => x.ImportantProperty != "P3")
  .ThenBy(c => c.Colour)
```

Comment: Interesting one, I had no idea you could do that.